# Protect external data file from unauthorized modifications

Tags: c++, qt

I am still learning QT, and this thing come to my mind: If I design a program and I want some data to be saved and protected, all the ways I know about saving data from QT Creator applications are writing into files which can be easily altered and deleted. Is there any way that I can safely store some application data and no one else can access it without breaking the application?

This might be a stupid question, but I am actually looking forward to some idea.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make it **impossible** to rewrite data for someone who has root/administrator access. You can however make the application refuse unauthorized changes and exit.

Assuming you want an external data file that can only be changed from within the application you can do something lie this:

Each time when the data file is changed by the application, calculate a hash value of the data, encrypt that and store it along the data file. Each time when reading the data, first hash the data, then read in the stored hash, decrypt it and compare it with the data hash. If it is not the same, exit the application.

This way if someone makes any changes from the outside, he will not be able to provide the accurate encrypted hash value for the data file, so the hash check will fail. Only someone who has the secret key will be able to make changes that the application will accept.

Comment: That sort of trick isn't hard to defeat with a disassembler. All you need to do is swap the comparison so that only when the data file hash **does** match you exit the application. Not that I would ever do such a thing... *cough*.

Comment: There is no uncrackable protection scheme. I highly doubt the OPs application would be considered a high value target worthy of disassembling and combing through the. A lot of professional grade software uses that same approach. It is more than adequate in that particular instance.

Comment: "That sort of trick isn't hard to defeat with a disassembler." There's no end to that, yet people do use copy protection. That's because the real world isn't binary :)

Comment: 99% of the key locks take like 2 seconds to pick with a pick gun, yet people still keep using them.